# How to access variable from nested function

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I want to pass the "galleryArr.length * 400;"out side the function onGalleryLoaded so I made the function "initmyWidth" and called it from outside the functions with "trace(initmyWidth());" but it gets an error "Call to a possibly undefined method initmyWidth"
is there a way to pass it one more level outside the functions?

```
function onGalleryLoaded(e:Event):void
    {

        var imageX:int = 0;
        var imageY:int = 0;


        for each (var image:Sprite in galleryArr)
        {

            var my_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

            my_mc.addChild(image);


            parent_mc.addChild(my_mc);

            my_mc.width = 400;
            my_mc.height = 400;
            my_mc.x -=  parent_mc.width;
            my_mc.y = imageY;

            function initmyWidth():Number
            {
                var myWidth:Number = galleryArr.length * 400;
                return myWidth;
            }


            imageX -=  my_mc.width + PADDING_X;
            if ( (imageX+my_mc.width) > stage.stageWidth )
            {
                imageX = parent_mc.width;
                imageY = 0;
            }

        }
    }

    trace(initmyWidth());
```

Comment: Do not nest functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested functions are anonymous, they cannot be accessed outside of the the parents functions scope. So **no, you cannot call it from outside**.

But you can simply put it as a class member and be able to use it without any difference.

Nested methods aren't evil, but they are mostly designed for non-stictly typed languages (e.g. JavaScript) and there is no need to use that in AS3.

The way to use nested functions if you want to dynamically create a function, e.g var myFunc = function(){}; and the be able to delete it by setting it to null. But in AS3 such functions have the longest call time and can be real performance hitters, so a rule of thumb - **don't use nested functions unless there's a really good reason to do it**.

Comment: Is funny becuse this isent really about nested or not nested, it's How can I get the math done out side of this function, I'm looking for parent_mc.width but it only give it to me here.

Comment: Well, the title of the question suggests that the question IS about nested functions and access to them.

And there is an answer - bring the desired function out as a class member or if you write in a frame just get it out from the parent function.

Comment: but thats the original problem I'm having i can get the number I need "I want to pass the "galleryArr.length * 400;"out side the function onGalleryLoaded" out side of onGalleryLoaded its always 0